# How I set the name of my downloader agent in Java, using the HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, web-crawler, httpurlconnection

I did a webcrawler and I want to set the name of my downloader agent to the sites knows who is acessing their content and to follow the robots.txt rules by name too.

How I do this?

Comment: Uhm, the question is not entirely clear, but are you basically asking how to set the `User-Agent` request header?

Comment: Hmmm, yes. I want to give a name to it and that the sites knows that is not Firefox, Chrome or a browser that is acessing, but an robot, my robot. There are some standard to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the [`User-Agent`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) request header using [`URLConnection#setRequestProperty()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). On `HttpURLConnection` this namely defaults to `java/xxx` where `xxx` is the version number.

E.g.

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "RenatoBot/1.0");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "yourDownloaderName")
```

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of the a User-Agent header with addRequestProperty or setRequestProperty

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)